# How to see tar content including uid and gid?

Tags: tar

I have a tar archive and want to see the content with the group-ids and user-ids. When using

```
tar --list -v --file file.tar
```

I see the user and group names, but I want to see the user-ids and group-ids instead. How can I achieve this? Or are the users itself stored in a tar archive, and not the ID?s?

Answer (score 6):

When you create a tar archive, the tar utility store the User ID.  When you show the content, it looks for the user in /etc/passwd, if it is found print the username, if not print the ID.

To avoid this behaviour try with the `--numeric-owner` option.

Answer (score 2):

Use `--to-command` option:

`tar xf file.tar --to-command 'echo $TAR_FILENAME:$TAR_UID:$TAR_GID'`

To see user and group names, rather than uid/gid:

`tar xf file.tar --to-command 'echo $TAR_FILENAME:$TAR_UNAME:$TAR_GNAME'`

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to extract, but merely list, this is better:

```bash
tar --list -tf data.tar.xz
```

## Example with `--numeric-owner`

```
$ tar --list --numeric-owner -tf data.tar.xz
```

```
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2013-07-15 04:41 ./
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2013-07-15 04:41 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2022-10-18 10:30 ./usr/bin/
-rwxrwxr-x 0/0              60 2022-10-18 10:25 ./usr/bin/furiusisomount
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2013-07-15 04:41 ./usr/share/
drwxr-xr-x 0/0               0 2013-07-15 04:41 ./usr/share/menu/
-rw-r--r-- 0/0             189 2013-07-11 17:14 ./usr/share/menu/furiusisomount
```

## Example without

```
$ tar --list -tf data.tar.xz
```

```
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2013-07-15 04:41 ./
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2013-07-15 04:41 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2022-10-18 10:30 ./usr/bin/
-rwxrwxr-x root/root        60 2022-10-18 10:25 ./usr/bin/furiusisomount
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2013-07-15 04:41 ./usr/share/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2013-07-15 04:41 ./usr/share/menu/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       189 2013-07-11 17:14 ./usr/share/menu/furiusisomount
```

Comment: Er, Alex _is_ using `--list` - what's your point?

Comment: `-t` is the important flag, not `--list`.

Comment: But `-t` means exactly the same as `--list`, so that adds nothing whatsoever.